# How can I change the rich-text editor to remove the "Heading 1" option

Tags: redactor, richtext

I want to remove the option to add a H1 from the dropdown in the Redactor rich-text component. I have edited the Standard.json file in craft>config>redactor to the below but it still hasn't done the job:

```
{
    "buttons": ["format","bold","italic","lists","link","horizontalrule"],
    "plugins": ["source","fullscreen"],
    "formattingTags": ["h2","h3","p","blockquote"]
}
```

I followed instructions from [this page](https://straightupcraft.com/articles/custom-redactor-toolbars-for-the-rich-text-field-in-craft-cms), but it looks like "formattingTags" doesn't work. Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`formattingTags` is not the correct syntax.

You should be using `formatting` instead, as per my answer on [this](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/15166/can-i-change-which-format-options-are-available-in-my-rich-text-field/15168) question.